# I have this countdown timer and i want it to start from a number set in a variable

Tags: vb.net

I have this count down timer and i want it to start to count down from a value given in a variable.

```
Public Class frmSinglePlayer

    Private TargetDT As DateTime
    Private CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)

    Private Sub frmSinglePlayer_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        tmrCountdown.Interval = 500
        TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
        tmrCountdown.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
            lblTime.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
        Else
            lblTime.Text = "00:00"
            tmrCountdown.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show("Done")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

I want to change instead of the number 3 in this line, to put the value from my variable.

```
Private CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)
```

I have 3 radiobuttons with different values.

```
Private Sub rd_1h_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rd_1h.CheckedChanged
    ho = 1
End Sub

Private Sub rd_2h_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rd_2h.CheckedChanged
    ho = 2
End Sub

Private Sub rd_3h_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rd_3h.CheckedChanged
    ho = 3
End Sub
```

If is confusing , please ask me and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You start the timer on form load, how do you intend to change the value of `ho` with a radio button before then?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
Private TargetDT As DateTime
Dim ho As Integer = 1

Private Sub StartTimerTick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs, Optional countDownFrom As Integer = 0)

    If sender Is Nothing Then
        TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(countDownFrom))
        Dim mTmr = New Timer
        mTmr.Interval = 500
        AddHandler mTmr.Tick, AddressOf StartTimerTick
        mTmr.Start()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("Tick ")


    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
    If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
        lblTime.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
    Else
        lblTime.Text = "00:00"
        CType(sender, Timer).Stop()
        CType(sender, Timer).Dispose()
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub rd_1h_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rd_1h.CheckedChanged,
                                                                           rd_2h.CheckedChanged,
                                                                           rd_3h.CheckedChanged


    Select Case CType(sender, Control).Name
        Case "rd_1h"
            ho = 1
        Case "rd_2h"
            ho = 2
        Case "rd_3h"
            ho = 3
    End Select

    'StartTimerTick(Nothing, Nothing, ho)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    StartTimerTick(Nothing, Nothing, ho)
End Sub
```